# I want shell code blocks executed via emacs org babel to be verbose, stoppable, interactable, asynchronous

Tags: org-mode

I want shell code blocks executed via emacs org babel to be

a) verbose - output should be shown live
b) stoppable
c) interactable
d) asynchronous

Has this been already done by a third party package/extension perhaps?

I also filed this as a [feature request](https://github.com/astahlman/ob-async/issues/42) with a [bounty](https://gitcoin.co/issue/astahlman/ob-async/42/1413).

Comment: I've seen babel packages that provide a) and d). b) shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: @bertfred I would be extremely interested in what you have seen that provides (a)

Comment: One approach that would solve (a), (b), and (d), would be to create a new org-babel language, that executes blocks via `async-shell-command`. I think this way would deliver (a) and (b) much more easily than the existing ob-async package which executes blocks in a separate emacs subprocess. The downside would be poorer support for multiple languages, but maybe multiple languages could be supported by adding a shebang at the top of the SRC block.

Answer (score 1):

Having all at the same time is tricky. However for a) and c) you can set a :session name parameter and then jump to the inferior buffer to debug what's going on. Once you have something working you can use ob-async and the :async key to run long running babel chunks as an asynchronous process.